flycheck causing stuttering while typing
I'm getting some performance issues where when I have flycheck-mode enabled in tex-mode/auctex, typing simple prose occasionally stutters for half a second.  This is resolved by disabling flycheck-mode.  Is there a setting that I can use e.g. to limit checking to the visible buffer or otherwise reduce the performance impact of flycheck short of disabling altogether?  I'd really like the functionality that flycheck provides without having to stop to request a check every couple minutes.
My question is similar to, but distinct from spacemacs: How can I disable flymake and flycheck completely, to speed up performance
